# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Adding Two Table using LinQ in datagridview Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq

This is my model class:

```
class LedgerDetailMaster
{
    public COA_LedgerDetails COA_LedgerDetails { get; set; }
    public COA_LedgerMaster cOA_LedgerMasterr { get; set; }

    public Int64 Ledger_ID { get; set; }
    public double Debit { get; set; }
    public double Credit { get; set; }
    public string Narration { get; set; }
    public string VNO { get; set; }
    public Int64 Ledgerr_ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime VDate { get; set; }
    public string VType { get; set; }
}
```

And the code I used is

```
var viewModels = db.COA_LedgerDetails.ToList();

var data = viewModels.Select(a => new LedgerDetailMaster
                   {
                    Ledger_ID = a.Ledger_ID,
                    Debit = a.debit,
                    Credit = a.cedit,
                    Narration = a.narration,
                    Ledgerr_ID = a.Ledger_ID,
                    VNO = a.cOA_LedgerMaster.VNO,
                    VDate = a.cOA_LedgerMaster.VDate,
                    VType = a.cOA_LedgerMaster.VType
                   }).ToList();

dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
```

I get this exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

`DTMSolERP.COA_LedgerDetails.cOA_LedgerMaster.get` returned null.

Comment: You must `Include` the referenced table/entity.

Comment: When i used to include this error occurs          'A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'DTMSolERP_dbModel.COA_ChequeMaster' does not declare a navigation property '.'

Comment: Is your db codefirst or dbfirst?

Comment: my db is dbfirst

Comment: The navigation properties need to be defined as `virtual`. Anyways, what has to do the `COA_ChequeMaster` entity with `COA_LedgerMaster`? Maybe you included the wrong entity?

Answer (score 0):

Your cOA_LedgerMaster is null because you not include it in your query.

```
var data = db.COA_LedgerDetails
  .Include(a => a.cOA_LedgerMaster)
  .Select(a => new LedgerDetailMaster
  {
     Ledger_ID = a.Ledger_ID,
     Debit = a.debit,
     Credit = a.cedit,
     Narration = a.narration,
     Ledgerr_ID = a.Ledger_ID,
     VNO = a.cOA_LedgerMaster.VNO,
     VDate = a.cOA_LedgerMaster.VDate,
     VType = a.cOA_LedgerMaster.VType
  }).ToList();
```

Be sure that your viewModel entity have a property named cOA_LedgerMaster and a foreign key associated for it (cOA_LedgerMasterId probably)

```
class LedgerDetailMaster
{
    public COA_LedgerMaster cOA_LedgerMasterr { get; set; }
    public int coA_LEdgerMasterrId {get; set; }
    ... // rest of your code
}
```

edit: you need to include the property in your first query

```
var viewModels = db.COA_LedgerDetails
  .Include(x => x.cOA_LedgerMaster)
  .ToList();
```

Anyway, you can rennounce at this query and apply dirrectly on first.

Comment: When i try to include as you suggested  an Error Occur            **A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'DTMSolERP_dbModel.COA_LedgerDetails' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'cOA_LedgerMaster'.'**

Comment: I have Ledger ID as cOA_LedgerMasterrID that is already included in the viewModel

Comment: are you sure you have a relationship between tables? maybe this can help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/relationships

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in the model class. Navigation properties need to be virtual and relationships should be in both the tables. Please follow the instructions at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships